# Where is F=BIL force exerted on my conductor?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetostatics

In order to get to the formula $F=BIL$ (L is the length of a wire,B a steady magnetic field,I a constant current) we integrate with respect to dl from 0 up to the length L of the straight wire. So the force is basically made up of many smaller forces dF.

When I'm asked to find the magnetic force on a current carrying wire do we mean the total force? If it were an infinite wire would the force be infinite?And finally, if this total force is exerted at a point, what is that point?

Maybe this has to do with mechanics since I have some gaps there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I'm asked to find the magnetic force on a current carrying wire do we mean the total force?

Usually, yes.

> If it were an infinite wire would the force be infinite?

If the field extends all the way to infinity - but usually you cannot make such a field so the region over which $B\times I$ is nonzero is finite.

> And finally, if this total force is exerted at a point, what is that point?

The "point" where this force could be said to be acting is the point where the first moment of force is zero. Just like the point where you could balance a see-saw (or teeter-totter depending on your country). It is analogous to the center of gravity (except it is the B field acting on current instead of gravity acting on mass...)

Comment: Just adding: for an infinite wire, it's more usual to compute the linear density of the force, so the length isn't an issue.